Delays in Call Execution During Half-Open State with Resilience4j Circuit Breaker in Spring Boot
I have implemented Circuit Breaker in my Spring Boot application using Resilience4j. The circuit breaker seems to be working fine overall, but I'm observing delays in call execution when it transitions to the half-open state. Calls should be attempted immediately within the half-open state, not wait for any additional delay.
Below is my configuration defined in the application.properties file:
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.register-health-indicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.sliding-window-size=2
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.sliding-window-type=TIME_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.minimum-number-of-calls=2
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.failure-rate-threshold=30
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.wait-duration-in-open-state=12000
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state=2
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.polling.automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled=true

Log Output :
Jul 05 17:49:18 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-47] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:49:18.373931+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from CLOSED to OPEN 
Jul 05 17:49:30 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [CircuitBreakerAutoTransitionThread] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:49:30.378576+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from OPEN to HALF_OPEN 
Jul 05 17:49:39 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-14] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:231 - CircuitBreaker 'polling' recorded an exception as failure: 
Jul 05 17:49:39 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-14] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:231 - CircuitBreaker 'polling' recorded an exception as failure: 
Jul 05 17:49:39 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-14] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:49:39.322654+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from HALF_OPEN to OPEN 
Jul 05 17:49:51 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [CircuitBreakerAutoTransitionThread] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:49:51.322865+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from OPEN to HALF_OPEN 
Jul 05 17:49:59 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:231 - CircuitBreaker 'polling' recorded an exception as failure: 
Jul 05 17:49:59 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-37] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:231 - CircuitBreaker 'polling' recorded an exception as failure: 
Jul 05 17:49:59 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [http-nio-8080-exec-37] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:49:59.507053+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from HALF_OPEN to OPEN 
Jul 05 17:50:11 ip-172-31-39-157 aggregator-stag [CircuitBreakerAutoTransitionThread] DEBUG i.g.r.c.i.CircuitBreakerStateMachine:379 - Event STATE_TRANSITION published: 2024-07-05T17:50:11.480387+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]: CircuitBreaker 'polling' changed state from OPEN to HALF_OPEN 

What could be causing these delays in the half-open state, and how can I resolve or mitigate them? Is there a specific configuration or best practice that I might be missing?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
